# Insensitivity of convergence in distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

I'm proving:

> If $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ and $\mathop{{}\mathbb{P}}\{X_n \neq Y_n\}\to 0$, then $Y_n \xrightarrow{d} X$.

My idea is to use almost sure representation of convergence in distribution, that is

> $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ iff their corresponding quantile $q_n \to q$ almost surely.

where we treat $q$ as random variable in $((0,1),\mathcal{B}_{(0,1)},\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure.

But I still have no idea of whether $\lambda\{q_n \neq q_n'\}\to 0$, where $q'_n$ is corresponding quantile of $Y_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(X_n \leq x)\leq P(X_n \neq Y_n)+P(Y_n \leq x)$ and

$P(Y_n \leq x)\leq P(X_n \neq Y_n)+P(X_n \leq x)$. The result follows from this.

Some details: Using the second inequality we get $\lim \sup P(Y_n \leq x) \leq \lim \sup P(X_n \leq x)=P(X\leq x)$ at continuity points of $F_X$. Similarly, the first inequality gives $\lim \inf P(Y_n \leq x) \geq \lim \inf P(X_n \leq x) =P(X\leq x)$ at continuity  points of $F_X$. So $P(Y_n \leq x) \to P(X\leq x)$ for $x$ in a dense set which implies that $Y_n \to X$ is distribution.